# Best bane weapon for Rise of the Runelords

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, optimization, rise-of-the-runelords

What would be the best bane weapon to have in the last module of Rise of the Runelords? Should I go for "giants" or "dragons"?

I am currently playing a level 15 dex based Magus with a +1 keen spell storing scimitar.

Comment: You are asking only about the last book (#6 Spires of Xin-Xalast), correct? Are you sure you want to be spoiled about what is coming ahead?

Comment: Eh. I'm the type of guy who likes to glimpse what's ahead.. Yes, last book only, but I do not ask for specific encounter description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did an enemy count on the [Spires of Xin-Xalast](http://paizo.com/products/btpy817c?Pathfinder-Adventure-Path-6-Spires-of-XinShalast), the last part of Rise of Runelords Adventure Path. Here are the results (beware of spoilers!):

- Animal: 24
- Humanoid (giant): 20
- Outsider (evil): 14
- Outsider: 8
- Magical Beast: 7
- Monstrous Humanoid: 6
- Undead: 6
- Humanoid: 4
- Dragon: 2
- Construct: 1
- Fey: 1
- Aberration: 1

Now, going a little more specific but without revealing too much:

> On giants, several are packed in a single encounter spread through several encounters. On animals, most are from one single encounter. On undead, half of them are from a single encounter and the others are spread. Outsiders you have nearly half of them on a single encounter, and the rest all spread out, so it's not a good idea to pick those unless you go chaotic/evil, which is why I counted them separately.

Knowing simply what the [Players Guide](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8bd9?Pathfinder-Adventure-Path-Rise-of-the-Runelords-Players-Guide) already suggests for ranger characters before you even open it (from the back cover):

> The Rise of the Runelords Anniversary Edition sets the groundwork for a thrilling Pathfinder RPG campaign that ranges from humble struggles with goblins, ghouls, and ogres to fantastic battles against **archmages, giants, and dragons**!

Here is what I would pick:

> The top two most seen type of creatures would be humanoid(giant) and outsider(evil). But if I were to specially prepare a weapon for this, I would go with **Humanoid(Giant)**. Archmages are present on the adventure and so are dragons, which make them really attractive types, but they are very few and you will need to survive before even facing them, so giants are a better option.

Answer (score 1):

Giants, because you consistently fight giant type enemies in many of the chapters.